# something about the django.contrib.auth.models source code

Tags: python, django, django-models

this is the last question I had made ,but it is still wrong way.  [it is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064641/typeerror-at-userregis-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-username?noredirect=1#comment55886094_34064641)  .   So

The traceback is here:

```
>>>from app1.models import UserReg

>>> UserReg.objects.create_user(username=u'hello world')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 187,
in create_user
    **extra_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 180,
in _create_user
    date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

I saw the models.py in django package but it seem that I have nothing wrong.So I would appericiate it if you can point where I am wrong in django's AbstracteUser model .

if you have anything need me to add , I would. Please , :((.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a field called username in your model, so you can't pass it to the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think, `UserReg` is your UserProfile model which has OneToOne Relation with django's user model from auth app.

then you need to create a new user using django's user model first

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.create_user(username='hello world')

userreg = UserReg(user=user) 
# we create UserReg instance for 'user'
# if UserReg has a 'user' OneToOne Field 

userreg.save()
```

Comment: Why I can't use AbstracteUser ,  do you have some articles for the usage of AbstracteUser ? and I will have a try  for this

Comment: @Bhhaha no need for abstractuser. just use the User model

Comment: but I extend the default User model by using abstracteuser, and it seems have another attributeerror.you can see the link I give.

Comment: @Bhhaha dont extend user model using abstractuser. this is not correct. extend it using normal user model

Comment: you means I should use AdstracteBaseUser not AbstracteUser? if it is , I will try .

Comment: @Bhhaha I mean neither of them. I mean `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry for this stupid question but meantime I am grateful for all the answers , which had made . In the past two days , I had looked alomst one hundred 
realative questions .Thanks.

=========================================

I forgot the the useage of `__init__()`,and I insert a parameter named `other name` but not named `username` in `__init__()`,so in the link , you can see the traceback.

last , thanks and I am a django fun.